# ASP.Net MVC Html.Raw not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, razor, html-helper

I'm having an issue with my ASP.Net MVC application, I'm using MVC 3 with Razor, and I cannot use the Raw extension method.

This is the error I get:

```
CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Raw'
and no extension method 'Raw' accepting a first argument of type
'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found.
```

I verified and the MVC dll version is 3.0, the target framework for the project is 4, I just have no idea of what is going on.

I even tried creating a new MVC 3 project from scratch but it doesn't work either.

EDIT:

This is the code I'm using for my Index.cshtml view on the test project (just a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project):

```
@{
    View.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@Html.Raw("<span>test</span>")
```

The error is exactly the same described above.

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Can you post some of your code?  The error message is helpful, but we can't really help without seeing some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed the issue.

I just went to http://www.asp.net/mvc and downloaded the standalone installer of MVC3, apparently there was something wrong with the version I was using (I installed it using WPI).

Now everything works as expected (including the ViewBag that wasn't working).

Comment: I installed the Asp Net MVC 3 Tools Update which resolved the issue.